# Grails Multi-Tenant No bean definition for tenantResolve

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to use Multi-Tenant Plugin with grails in STS.For this i made an entry in BuildConfig.groovy which is compile ":multi-tenant-single-db:0.8.3" and i followed some instructions like commands: "install-plugin multi-tenant-single-db" after this one more command which is : "mt-quickStart" which successfully installed my plugin.

Now i created one domain class:

```
@MultiTenant
class UserInfo {

String address
String email
Long mobile

Long age
static constraints = {

    email email:true,nullable:true,blank:false
    mobile nullable:true,blank:false,size:10..13
    age nullable:true,blank:false
    address nullable:true,blank:false
}
}
```

But when ever i try to run my project[image: Error after running project]

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to define a `tenantResolver` in resources.groovy:

```
beans {
    //Make sure to import!
    tenantResolver(MyCustomTenantResolver)
}
```

[Reference](http://multi-tenant.github.io/grails-multi-tenant-core/guide/3.%20Configure%20a%20Tenant%20Resolver.html)